# Bash: Inline Iterate over multiple values

Tags: bash

Morning,

I'm currently in a situation where I have to repeat a command for several datasets and am wondering, if there is a more elegant solution than nesting loops or building a dedicated program.

So basically something like:

```
> echo "Hello from [NYC,Chicago] to [Berlin,Paris]"
Hello from NYC to Berlin
Hello from NYC to Paris
Hello from Chicago to Berlin
Hello from Chicago to Paris
```

Sure, some "`for i in x,y,z`"-magic would work, but that gets hard to read as soon as multiple datasets are involved.

Is there a way to easily iterate over multiple datasets in Bash? How would you solve this to keep it somewhat readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brace expansion.

```
printf '%s\n' 'Hello from '{NYC,Chicago}' to '{Berlin,Paris}
```

Note that it doesn't work for variables, only for literal values (as brace expansion happens before variable expansion).

Comment: Sounds just like what I was looking for - all in one place and easy to grasp. `echo` in my question was more of an example, but piping the output back to bash should work fine for small scripts you only use/feed with data yourself.

`printf '%s\n' 'iptables -A FORWARD -i '{NYC,Chicago}' -o '{Berlin,Paris} | bash`

Answer (score 0):

If it's a quick one-off then a [brace expansion](https://superuser.com/a/1770491/332907) would be quick and easy. If you're looking for a programmatic variation then a couple of loops might be more suitable.

Example 1, with trivially short datasets

```
# Iterate until done
for colour in red green blue
do
    for shape in square triangle circle
    do
        printf "> %s - %s <\n" "$colour" "$shape"
    done
done
```

Example 2, with larger datasets

```
# Prepare the scenario with two files, "colourfile" and "shapefile"
cat >colourfile <<'X'
red
green
blue
X

cat >shapefile <<'X'
square
triangle
circle
X

# Loop until done
while IFS= read -r colour
do
    while IFS= read -r shape
    do
        printf "> %s - %s <\n" "$colour" "$shape"
    done <shapefile
done <colourfile
```

This will read `shapefile` once through for each entry in `colourfile`. Fortunately disk caching will help mitigate the repeated I/O. If you are really concerned then reading the inner file into an array would trade disk accesses for memory usage.

Output for both examples

```
> red - square <
> red - triangle <
> red - circle <
> green - square <
> green - triangle <
> green - circle <
> blue - square <
> blue - triangle <
> blue - circle <
```